# Must an automorphism on the group of real numbers under multiplication maintain sign?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, real-numbers

Suppose we have an automorphism $\phi$ under the group $(\mathbb{R}^{\#},\,\cdot)$.  I need to show that $\phi$ preserves the sign of the numbers, or that $\phi(\mathbb{R}^+)=\mathbb{R}^+$ and $\phi(\mathbb{R}^-)=\mathbb{R}^-$.

I've had a bit of success.  I determined fairly painlessly that $\phi(r)>0\iff\phi(r^{-1})>0$ for any $r\in\mathbb{R}^\#$.  But I'm having difficulty making any other sort of progress.  My guess is that there's something trivial that I'm missing that I'm currently just too blind to see, but either way, I'm a bit frustrated with my stagnancy here.  Any help or hints or suggestions would really help.

For reference, the only thing I really know about automorphisms is the fact that they're bijective and that it preserves the identity (in this case) $\phi(a) \cdot \phi(b)=\phi(a \cdot b)$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^\#$.

Comment: Just to be clear because the title and body of your question seem to be conflicting. You mean automorphism of the real numbers under multiplication, right?

Comment: Do you mean $\Bbb R^{\times}$, the group of nonzero real numbers under multiplication?

Comment: Shoot.  I'm too tired...  I edited the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Use that $\phi(a^2)=(\phi(a))^2$

Comment: What a clever little tactic.  Thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 1):

Can you think of a property, in terms of multiplication only, that positive numbers have but negative ones don't? (HINT: think about $x^2$ . . .)